AWS Elastic Beanstalk Errors: Auto Scaling Group and Launch Configuration Issues
I'm trying to deploy an application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I'm encountering the following errors related to CloudFormation and Auto Scaling:
1, Auto Scaling Launch Configuration Issue:
Creating Auto Scaling launch configuration failed
Reason: Resource handler returned message:
"The Launch Configuration creation operation is not available in your account.
Use launch templates to create configuration templates for your Auto Scaling groups.
(Service: AutoScaling, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 3a5bbee3-54bd-48e7-830d-a3ecfa866555)"
2, Stack Operation Aborted:
Stack named 'awseb-e-xqupckfmms-stack' aborted operation.
Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED'
Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration].
3, CloudFormation Error:
Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Resource AWSEBAutoScalingGroup does not exist for stack awseb-e-xqupckfmms-stack
Environment Setup:
I set up an Elastic Beanstalk environment with a high-availability configuration.
Configured the environment with an EC2 key pair and attached required permissions (e.g., CloudWatchLogsFullAccess, AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier, AmazonS3FullAccess, ElasticLoadBalancingFullAccess).
Checked Permissions:
Verified the IAM roles and instance profiles have the correct permissions for creating and managing resources like Auto Scaling Groups and CloudFormation stacks.

Could it have something to do with the following link?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-autoscaling-launch-templates.html
AWS has disabled creating new Launch Configurations and only allows new Launch Templates. But it looks like they haven't fully updated Beanstalk to account for that. According to the link, when creating an environment you need to do one of the following to get Beanstalk to use templates:

RootVolumeType option set to gp3. You can set this option with the
console or the namespace.
BlockDeviceMappings option contains gp3. You can set this option with the console or the namespace.
DisableIMDSv1 option set to true. We recommend that you set this
option using the namespace.
EnableSpot option set to true. For more information, see Spot
instance support and Configuration Auto Scaling group configuration.

